# Downvoting or deleting coding style questions

Tags: discussion, questions, scope

I asked a question about code style [Which of these styles of golang code (if any) is objectively most legible/best?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58546902/which-of-these-styles-of-golang-code-if-any-is-objectively-most-legible-best) (copy of question content below in case it is deleted) and it is being thretened with deletion or closing. The cited reason looks to be that opinion based answers are what people generally respond with or that the question has no objective answer to it.

I would agree that opinion based answers to this type of question are common and undesired, but it is fundamentally incorrect that there is no objective evidence based decisions possible on code styling.

I assume that people often respond incorrectly to this type of question (I mean that they respond with their preference without any supporting evidence). Is there really no other option for treating questions people respond to incorrectly than to remove them? This response makes all questions about design, taste, legibility, etc. not allowed. Its already hard enough to find good quality information about these types of things.

Instead of removing or closing these types of questions, lets focus on the quality of the questions and especially the answers.

---

Referenced question from above

---

```golang
err := a.DB.Q().
  LeftJoin("businesses", "businesses.id = pharmacies.business_id").
  LeftJoin("contacts", "contacts.id = businesses.contact_id").
  Where("key <> ''").
  Select(
    "contacts.name AS business_name",
    "pharmacies.id AS pharmacy_id",
    "pharmacies.name AS pharmacy_name",
    "last_connect", "last_disconnect").All(&results)
```

vs

```golang
err := a.DB.Q(
).LeftJoin(
  "businesses",
  "businesses.id = pharmacies.business_id",
).LeftJoin(
  "contacts", "contacts.id = businesses.contact_id",
).Where("key <> ''").Select(
  "contacts.name AS business_name",
  "pharmacies.id AS pharmacy_id",
  "pharmacies.name AS pharmacy_name",
￼  "last_connect", "last_disconnect",
).All(&results)
```

Which of these styles of golang code (if any) is objectively most legible/best?

I was unable to find a statement on this question directly in https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html (not that authority alone is the best evidence), and `go fmt` left either option as it was.

To avoid/reduce subjectivity please provide objectivly verifiable evidence for why your answer is valid. I put the word "objective" in the title because this kind of question can get answers that are posed in a subjective way.

An example answer

---

The second is better for these reasons:

- It is close in style to the existing common way to do chain calls in other languages https://codeburst.io/javascript-learn-to-chain-map-filter-and-reduce-acd2d0562cd4?gi=d851d13ffa73
- The second line in the first one

```golang
  LeftJoin("businesses", "businesses.id = pharmacies.business_id").
```

is over 60 characters long which decreases readability https://baymard.com/blog/line-length-readability

- It is easier to miss the fact that these functions are chained since the period is at the end of the line

  - I don't have a source to cite, but maybe some reasonable hypothesis
  - Characters nearer to the ends of lines are less likely to be noticed
  - Periods are very small (often taking up very few pixels) so are more easily missed than other characters
  - Moving less prominate characters to the beginning of a line helps to counteract the ease of missing them

Comment: Stack Overflow has been around for over a decade now and has experience with these types of questions. The result of those years of experience? These types of questions just don't work.

Comment: If you want a review of your coding style in a Stack Exchange-style format, try [CodeReview.SE]. Contrary to your assertions, none of what you presented in your example answer is actually “objective”. It is just a well-reasoned opinion. This is not the type of Q&A that Stack Overflow is intended to handle.

Comment: @HereticMonkey What do you mean they do not work? They don't get good answers?

Comment: @CodyGray How is a study that shows that line length is correlated negatively with reading comprehension an opinion and not objective? Using this study as evidence you can form a reasonable hypothesis that a coding style that uses very long lines is objectively not as good as one that doesn't.

I don't understand why this is a well-reasoned opinion and not objective evidence

Comment: Uhh...couple of things. First, that study you cite is about line length in written prose. Prose is read very differently from code, so it isn’t at all clear that the same rules apply. Second, there are implicit value judgments there, which are entirely non-objective. Third, even to the extent to which that particular argument is objective, there are other arguments that could be made which are equally objective, thus creating an irresolvable impasse. Again, this is not the type of thing SO is designed to handle. “Which of these do you find most readable/best style?” is inherently opinion-based

Comment: They get opinions, not objective statements of fact. You may cite a study showing that line length is negatively correlated with reading comprehension, but I point you to http://tylervigen.com/view_correlation?id=29010, showing that "Drownings caused by an accident involving a fishing boat inversely correlates with UK: Military defense spending".

Comment: @Heretic Well, that makes sense. As UK military defense spending goes up, more of the US’s boat-making industry is focused on building items to sell to the UK for defense, which means they aren’t building as many fishing boats. Thus, there are fewer fishing boats to get into accidents with swimmers, so you have less drownings.

Comment: @CodyGray You make a good point with the difference between written prose and code likely making those findings not transfer as well onto code. I agree that there are implicit value judgements in the question, but all questions are meant to do 2 things: try to establish the criteria or values by which an answer can be judged as good or correct, and explain the needed details about the situation. I agree that other answers that look equally objective will come up. This often happens on normal coding questions too, 1 answer runs faster with 1 cpu, another with more cpus, another is in func style

Comment: You can't turn an opinionated question into an unopinionated one by merely adding the word "objective" to it.  Despite your assertion, the phrase "objectively most legible" is a contradiction in terms, like "plastic glass."

Comment: Yeah, optimization questions are also tricky. They only work here if there are criteria explicitly defined in the question. But perhaps “opinion-based” is a red herring here. The more fundamental issue is just that SO doesn’t do coding style questions. Those aren’t practical programming problems within our defined scope. Part of the reason we don’t is, of course, because they tend to be opinion-based. But there are other reasons, too, and at this point, it has really just become a policy. Much like how we don’t do recommendation questions, no matter how objectively you define criteria.

Comment: @Robert: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poly(methyl_methacrylate) (“Although not a type of familiar silica-based glass, the substance, like many thermoplastics, is often technically classified as a type of glass (in that it is a non-crystalline vitreous substance)…”)

Comment: @RobertHarvey I agree that people are very opinionated about code-style, but that does not mean that there is no evidence that exists or will ever exist that can be used to inform your desicions on coding style better than trial and error.

Comment: @SultanLegend coding styles are mostly subjective opinions though. Somebody (or few people) come along and say "this looks OK to me" and write a coding style saying "Only write it in this fashion". Style guides don't really have decisions at random but pick one of the *many* valid ones. Consistency is good, even if two lines of code do the same thing while looking vastly different, being consistent is always preferable. *That* is what coding style is mostly about, rather than picking the optimal way to write code. Because there isn't one.

Comment: @VLAZ I agree that the general way that code is written in a specific language plays a huge part of what style you should use. I agree that we don't know the optimal way to write code, but that does not mean we don't have the means to judge parts of a style to be worse than others. I agree that an answer saying "Only write it in this fashion" and "this looks OK to me" are not good answers. They do not provide a way to know the quality of the answer.

Comment: "*I agree that we don't know the optimal way to write code, but that does not mean we don't have the means to judge parts of a style to be worse than others*" that only works up to some point, though. If a code style says "name all variables after a combination of colour and animal, e.g., greenHorse, redGiraffe, etc" then that's worse than "write descriptive names for variables, e.g., counter, personName, etc.". But is `nameOfPerson` worse than `personName`? Or what about `sPersonName`? These are equivalent in use - clear *enough*. Preference will depend on context.

Comment: One thing I like is "it's hard enough to find good information about this". This seems to be a very cited reason to turn to Stack... "But I couldn't find it elsewhere!". How is that Stack's issue? No offense to you, but Stack decided to not entertain these questions. Maybe the fact that it's hard to find good info here doesn't fit with Stack's goal of being a "be all end all repo of programming knowledge"

Comment: @Patrice it's more about *specific* programming problems. "I've been trying to do algorithm X" or "I want to do Y with my editor of choice" or "I keep getting error Z". That sort of stuff. "Do you *prefer* A or B?" isn't really a programming question, if it doesn't have a clear cut answer.

Comment: @Patrice I'm trying to improve SO, not say that it owes this to me. I think the main reason people ask questions on SO is "But I couldn't find it elsewhere!" and "it's hard enough to find good information about this". I think its the only reason almost all questions get asked. Why would people ask if they already found a good enough answer somewhere else? I would argue that SO's, and most SE sites's, main use is to fill the gap where someone couldn't find it elsewhere. It seems to me that things difficult to find elsewhere fit well within "be all end all repo of programming knowledge"

Comment: @Sultan with a narrow scope. I'm not saying you are entitled. You're actually very rational about your points :p. But a lot of people come here with that sentiment of "if it's about programming and I can't find it, *it has to belong on Stack*".... which isn't true :/. And "be all end all" also means "objectively correct".... so an objective answer that can change over time makes it... very difficult

Comment: @Patrice Do you think that code style questions and answers don't belong on stackoverflow but maybe on another stackexchange site or that they don't fit anywhere on any stackexchange site?

Comment: @Sultan personally? I'd say they are very hard to fit anywhere. There's a *lot* of subjectivity in code styles (heck, I hate some of the previous styles I used.... so even I am not consistent over time). I don't think there are a lot of "objective" rules about code style that can be truly pointed out to mean it's "clearer". With a very clear scope (what is "clearer" for you?).... maaaaaybe?

Comment: @SultanLegend it is very unlikely any of SE sites will allow such type of opinion-based questions. Definitely none of programing-related once.

Comment: @gnat I'm arguing that people fill in gaps in reasoning or subsitute instantaneous preference for reason (I like it this way, and I don't think about why), but that does not mean that we can't have reasonable discussions, answers, etc. that lay out and explore factors that can and often should inform decisions and preferences. "What color of shirt is best?" can be usefully answered with "tee-shirts are cheaper than button up long sleeves _citation or justification_ so they are likely cheaper" or "blue dye is cheaper than others _citation_" (true in the case of plastic if I remember correctly).

Comment: @SultanLegend you are providing arguments *against* your suggestion that such questions should be on-topic - "having discussions" is exactly what SO is trying to avoid. ("The best" as in "cheaper"??? that is even more opinion based opinion that all opinions expressed before :) )

Comment: @SultanLegend even that "objective" shirts example is opinion based. You've asked for *best* yet your suggestion for fitting answers is *cheapest*. That's not the only interpretation here, nor is that metric universally most useful. Some people might prefer *durability* even for higher price and there might be some scientific study that green shirts are more durable. Others might prefer the white or black for the ease to colour coordinate. So, "best" is still subjective, because price is but one objective measure that is not everyone's highest priority. And each of their preferences is valid.

Comment: Fair enough. This is a QA site not a disscussion site.

Answer (score 3):

Vote to close as "opinion-based".

There is generally no reason to downvote coding style questions. Such questions may even collect upvotes ("I'd like to know answer too" kind of votes) but that does not make them on-topic.

Please note that different sites on StackExchange network have different rules about what is "opinion-based" question and some *look* even encouraging that - questions on politics, law and sceptics *feel* more opinion-based to me for example. On StackOverflow coding style questions are simply considered to be off-topic and no amount of "this article says so" in an answer will make it on-topic.

Note that code style questions are off-topic because vast majority of those have no objective criteria to judge the answers. I know of one example where particular coding style is objectively safer (curly placement in JavaScript) but on-topic version of the question would be "Is there reason why same line curly is safer in JavaScript" rather than "What curly style to pick for JavaScript".

You are free to propose change to that policy on meta if you have good arguments to show how such questions do in general have objective answer.